# AppleScript Beginner: Expected end of line but found identifier

Tags: html, ms-word, applescript, macos-big-sur

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    insert text "property eGrepx : "priceValue___11gHJ\">\\$\\d{2},\\d{3}.\\d{2}"
" at end of text object of active document
end tell
```

The following code returns a syntax error: **Expected end of line but found identifier** and points to "priceValue___11gHJ". This is the html code that I need to write to the file and it can't be changed. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I do not have **Microsoft Word**, however I would think that the `" ` in front of `at end of text object of active document` should not be there **and**  `at end of text object of active document` should be on the same line as `insert text ...`.

Comment: Well that helped but now it's another error with what I want to write to text.

Comment: I found that replacing the "\"s with a letter gets rid of the error. I can just find/replace all later down the line I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your command has two pairs of quotation marks. As the inner pair is part of the quoted text, each must be escaped. Add a backslash before **"pricevalue**.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    
    insert text "property eGrepx : \"priceValue___11gHJ\">\\$\\d{2},\\d{3}.\\d{2}" at ¬
        end of text object of active document
    
end tell
```

Then, the following text will be inserted into your word doc:

```
property eGrepx : "priceValue___11gHJ">\$\d{2},\d{3}.\d{2}
```

The error indicated that because the second quote was not escaped, the line should have ended there — but it obviously didn't. It's really telling you that the syntax ended things prematurely.

Comment: yeah it was tricky to figure out how to enter it because of its syntax. I just replaced the " with Ω and the \ √ and I will find/replace all when I'm further along on the project.